# Debugger can't connect to UE4

Tags: debugging, unreal-engine4

I just started using Visual Studio 2013 Express and when I run the debugger it seems like it can't connect to UE4, for more information:

[image]

I tried momentarily disabling the firewall, closing Skype, didn't help.

The project builds, but when UE4 is trying to lunch that pop up appears, followed by another one saying that the debugger couldn't launch.

Comment: Are you able to start UE without debugging?

Comment: Yeah, without debugging it worked if I remember correctly. I didn't try this yet again, I formatted and bought a new PC since then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Support/Builds, select your version of ue4 and search the page for "visual studio" - there should be a note regarding which version of VS is supported for each release.